# Completely Stuck in Caravan Progression

Tags: monster-hunter-4-ultimate

I'm completely stuck in progression of the single player content. I have reached 6 Star quests with the caravan, but there are no more quests offered to me.

I would provide a screenshot if I knew how to make one. My situation is this: I did all the quests offered. But the check mark on the 6 Star quests is only silver, indicating there are undiscovered quests left. I have checked every location in the game, but there are no more speech bubbles.

What is strange is that the box for the urgent quests is still there, with two quests, both checked as well, I have done both.

So, did I miss something? There are no more hints in the game, and after searching in the net I seem to be the only one having this problem.

Comment: Have you fought Shagaru Magala yet? How about Damiyo Hermitaur?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to play Guild quest and increase your HR (Hunter Rating) to 4 so you can unlock the first batch of missing 6* caravan quests.

To unlock all the 6 Stars caravan quests you need to reach HR7

quests are unlocked at HR 4, 5 ,6 ,7

Guild quest are a bit harder tan caravan quests but you can do them alone or with friends ( or any online player that joins if you create a online instance)

EDIT: I wanted to add that for some of the quest to appear you need to talk with different NPC in different towns after reaching the necesary HR

Comment: Do you need a certain HR to get to high rank in the caravan? As far as I know the online stuff only unlocks "bonus" quests like the other 6* quests or 10* quests.

Comment: You don't need a certain HR to Access high Rank in the caravan, once you reach dundorma and start doing 7 stars or higher then you are already in high Rank.

Comment: It's worth noting that some of the caravan quests with HR prereqs actually have high rank monsters in them, and take place in high rank areas.